# Dart: List remove not removing Object

Tags: dart

The code is on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/65b4759b98d08ae1862e) if you need a complete example (see the `while` loop towards the end.)

I have a loop,

```
Place place = places[0];
while (places.isNotEmpty) {
  // Get a list of places within distance (we can travel to)
  List reachables = place.getReachables();

  // Get the closest reachable place
  Place closest = place.getClosest(reachables);

  // Remove the current place (ultimately should terminate the loop)
  places.remove(place);

  // Iterate
  place = closest;
}
```

But it's not removing `place` on the second-to-last line. i.e., the length of the `places` list remains the same, making it an infinite loop. What's wrong?

Comment: you can try this answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569910/12121284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `place` is not in the list for some reason. It's hard to debug without knowing the exact data used, the problem doesn't reproduce with the three-place sample you have in the linked DartPad.

Try figuring out which element is causing the problem. For example you can
try adding an `if (!places.contains(place)) print("!!! $place not in $places");` before the remove, or something similar that detects the state when the problem occurs.

Comment: The `place = places[0]; while(...) { places.remove(place); }` [error] is confounding to me. And nowhere else am I removing from the `places` list. I'm sure it's a bug in my code, I'll keep hacking on it.

Comment: you can try this answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569910/12121284

Answer (score 5):

This could be because the object in the list has a different hashCode from the object you are trying to remove.

Try using this code instead, to find the correct object by comparing the objects properties, before removing it:

```
var item = list.firstWhere((x) => x.property1== myObj.property1 && x.property2== myObj.property2, orElse: () => null);

list.remove(item);
```

Another option is to override the == operator and hashCode in your class.

```
class Class1 {
  @override
  bool operator==(other) {
    if(other is! Class1) {
      return false;
    }
    return property1 == (other as Class1).property1;
  }

  int _hashCode;
  @override
  int get hashCode {
    if(_hashCode == null) {
      _hashCode = property1.hashCode
    }
    return _hashCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try this answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569910/12121284

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the very same issue. Unfortunately I haven't found the root cause, but in the same situation I replaced

`places.remove[place]`

with

`places.removeWhere(p => p.hachCode == place.hashCode)`

as a workaround. One more approach was helpful too:

```
// Get the place from your set:
final place = places.first;
// Replace the place in the set:
places.add(place);
// Remove the place from the set:
places.remove(place);
```

Comment: you can try my answer :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569886/12121284

Answer (score 0):

This way you can remove object from dynamic list

```
List data = [
    {
      "name":"stack"
    },
    {
      "name":"overflow"
    }
  ];
  
  data.removeWhere((item) => item["name"]=="stack");
  
  print(data);
```

> Output

```
[{name: overflow}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the plugin Equatable

class Place extends Equatable {
...
}

https://pub.dev/packages/equatable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I did something like this using `removeWhere`.

```
myList.removeWhere((item) => item.id == yourItemId.id)
```