# List addAll throw error :Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration:

Tags: list, listview, flutter, dart

What is actually happening?

**main.dart**

In `initState`, we are calling server to get image from database, then add it into sink

```
var capturedImagesList = List<dynamic>();

    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();  
         _bloc.getImages(); // 
        });
      }
```

**bloc class**

```
  final _urlImage = BehaviorSubject<List<dynamic>>();
  get urlImageSink => _urlImage.sink;
  get urlImageStream => _urlImage.stream;

 Future getImages() async {
    Response image = await _repo.getImages();  // call server
    var imageResponse = Response.fromJson(image.body);
    urlImageSink.add(imageResponse.images);  // add image to sink
  }
```

The retrieved image will be displayed in horizontal `ListView`.

[image]

When the + image is clicked, it will allow user to select an image from gallery, then placed beside the `ListView` as image below.

[image]

Everything works fine !

But when I click the + image again to add one more image, it throw us this error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception:
>   Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:3) of
>   '_GrowableList'. E/flutter (32313): #0      List.addAll 
>   (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:187:11)

**main.dart**

This is the code after image is selected from gallery.

```
 @override
  List<dynamic> userImage(File images) {
    if (images != null) {
      capturedImagesList.add(images.path);  // add selected image to List
      capturedImagesList.addAll(_bloc.urlImageStream.value);  // add the server image to list
       _bloc.urlImageSink.add(capturedImagesList);  // add all images to list
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Errror is pointed to this line

```
capturedImagesList.addAll(_bloc.urlImageStream.value);
```

Why it works for the first time, but failed for second time?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @rajithShetty yes

Comment: @JohnJoe what was the solution?

Comment: @AjayGautam I use for loop at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do that

```
_bloc.urlImageSink.add([images])
```

And the image would reflected immediately in UI.

I think the problem is in this line

```
capturedImagesList.addAll(_bloc.urlImageStream.value);
```

this looks strange, you can't copy the stream into array, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check out this thread: [Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:17) of '_GrowableList'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409666/exception-concurrent-modification-during-iteration-instancelength17-of-gr)

I quote from the article:

> This error means that you are adding or removing objects from a collection during iteration. This is not allowed since adding or removing items will change the collection size and mess up subsequent iteration.

So I don't see all the code, but could it be that when you add a picture via the add button, you clear the list or remove the current items?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the array like this before doing `addAll`

```
  _myLeaveRequests?.clear();
```