# Nested FutureBuilder's snapshot that already create still there when re-visit with new query

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, dart, firebase-realtime-database

There is material application to query database to display items in category.

1. Page [Category] - select category A (Passed parameter as category id A)
2. Page [Items] - (Only items A was query from the database) ListView.builder display items of category A correctly
3. Then click back
4. Page [Category] -> select category B (Passed parameter as category id B)
5. Page [Items] -> (Only items B was query from the database) ListView.builder unexpected display items of category A and B

Note: I need calling condition future function to display items then I called FutureBuilder as nested of StreamBuilder. It's working fine until we need to have a category of item. Which leading to result of StreamBuilder can be difference. Then observed snapshot of FutureBuilder is not clean up well.

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: firestoreInstance.collection('items').where("category", isEqualTo: widget.categoryId).snapshots(),  

   builder: (context, snapshot1) {     
     if (!snapshot1.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();          
     else return _buildList(context, snapshot1.data.documents);
   },   
 );
}

Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> docSnapshot) {
 return FutureBuilder <List<ItemsRecord>> (
      future: getDetailsOfEachItem(context, docSnapshot),
      builder: (context, snapshot2) {
         if (snapshot2.hasData == true) { 
            return new ListView.builder(
                         itemCount: snapshot2.data.length,
                         itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index)
                         {
                           return _buildListItem(context, snapshot2.data[index]);
                         }
                        );
          }
          else
          {
             return Container(hieght: 0);
          }
       });
}
```

By debugging database result of query (By StreamBuilder) items is correct. Only B available.

```
Debugging result of step above.
snapshot1 => Category A => 15 items
snapshot1=> Category B => 6 items
```

But look like items A in FutureBuilder in snapshot are still exist.

```
Debugging result of step above.
snapshot2 => Category A => 15 items
snapshot2 => Category A & B => 21 items (Unexpected !)
```

Please help to suggest how cloud I remove unexpected item A in snapshot2 of FutureBuilder.

I try to add snapshot2.data.clear(); but seem like data is null when hasData is not true, also when ConnectionState is waiting.

Try refer to snapshot2.requireData instead of snapshot2.data also same result.

Comment: Add more code and context please, we cannot guess what else you did

Comment: @AlbertoMiola Added multiple line of code and explanation, hopefully you understand my code and current result of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try added forEach to manually remove found Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:21) of '_GrowableList'

Search around then realized dart has an options that during interations we can mark items for removal and then remove them in a bulk operation with removeWhere. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409666/exception-concurrent-modification-during-iteration-instancelength17-of-gr)

This code is working fine for me.

```
Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> docSnapshot) {
 return FutureBuilder <List<ItemsRecord>> (
      future: getDetailsOfEachItem(context, docSnapshot),
      builder: (context, snapshot2) {
         if (snapshot2.hasData == true) { 

            List<ItemsRecord> records = snapshot2.data;
            List toRemove = [];

            records.forEach((record) {
                if (record.category != widget.categoryId)
                {
                   toRemove.add(record);
                }
            });
            
            records.removeWhere( (e) => toRemove.contains(e));

            return new ListView.builder(
                         itemCount: snapshot2.data.length,
                         itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index)
                         {
                           return _buildListItem(context, snapshot2.data[index]);
                         }
                        );
          }
          else
          {
             return Container(hieght: 0);
          }
       });
}
```

Thanks to Alberto Miola, I think his question trigger me to try dig into problem to explain and that make me simply found the answer. Actually, we should call it workaround.